# Codemaid did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, codemaid

I have MSVS 2013 and Windows 7.
I'v tried to install Codemaid, but there is a mistake, when I launch a studio:

```
The 'CodemaidPackage' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the 
installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining 
the file 
'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
```

There are some errors from Log:

```
<errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>

<description>Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip flag</description>
```

May somebody give an advice?

Comment: Well I described the solution that worked for me in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531738/visual-studio-2019-package-did-not-load-correctly/72915407#72915407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what version of .NET you have installed?  Starting with CodeMaid v10.3, .NET 4.6.2 was required.

There's some more information here: https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/443

If that doesn't answer your question, opening issues directly on the repository is usually the best way to get help.  https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can help you there is a known bug
https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/634