# Visual Studio 2019 - Package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, package

Recently I started getting an error whenever I open Visual Studio 2019. The error always states something along the lines of "package did not load correctly" or "unknown error". This bug is reoccurring and effects all versions of Visual Studio that I have installed (2015, 2017, & 2019), and even effects the Visual Studio Installer and Developer's Console.

This started after installing Xampp and php for WordPress development, so I feel those files may be involved somehow, maybe it is a conflict with Apache and IIS, but I'm not sure. I will post some of the error message text below.

> The 'SccProviderPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
>   installation of another extension. You can get more information by
>   examining the file
>   'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_9*******\ActivityLog.xml'
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.
>
> The 'VS Setup Composition' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
>   installation of another extension. You can get more information by
>   examining the file
>   'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_9*******\ActivityLog.xml'
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Comment: yeah, it happened to me but different version of MS Visual Studio. It happened after some updates on the Visual Studio. What I did was to unload the project/package and then load it again. It happened every now and then and it is not a permanent solution

Comment: Unfortunately my only option after searching around was to complete restore my entire computer, then redownload VS and all my projects. There still doesn't seem to be any kind of clear explanation as to what causes it or how to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

I upgraded Live Share on Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.6 and the error begun to appear everytime I opened a solution.
What worked for me is:
Under Extensions => Manage Extensions => Installed, disable Live Share and Enable it again.
Restart Visual studio.
That worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: I got the same problem when installing the Upgrade Assistant Package extension, and your solution just worked for me. Incredible.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I was installing the last version of `CodeMaidv12`. What It worked was to Uninstall that version and install and old one (that suits well with VS2029) `CodeMaid v10.6` what it worked was:

1. Uninstall `CodeMaid` from `Extensions/Installed/CodeMaid` press `Uninstall` button
2. Go to CodeMaid GitHub site and search [CodeMaid v10 release](https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/releases/download/v10.6/CodeMaid.v10.6.144.vsix) download it.
3. Close VS2019
4. Install `CodeMaid v10`
5. Open VS2019 => `Extensions/CodeMaid/Options` (it should be working).
6. Important extra step be sure to have unchecked the updates option on `CodeMaid` (as in picture)
   [image]